# Overriding generic method of raw type

Tags: java, generics

I have generic class with generic method

```
class Foo<T> {
    public <E> E execute() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me why this:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    public <E> E execute() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

produces error

> execute() in Bar clashes with execute() in Foo; both methods have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

whereas this is ok

```
class Bar extends Foo<Object> {
    public <E> E execute() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A *raw type* has no generic methods, hence, when extending `Foo`, you are inheriting the erased method `public Object execute()`. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you use the raw type of Foo, so Foo's method signature is `public Object execute()`. This clashes with the generic version in `Bar`. This is actually easily reproducible without inheritance like so:

```
class Foo
{
    public <E> E execute() { return null; }
    public Object execute() { return null; }
}
```

In the second example you are not using the raw type of `Foo` so the signatures of the `execute` methods are an exact match. In this case it's just a simple method override. As such, you should probably annotate it.

```
class Bar extends Foo<Object> {
    @Override
    public <E> E execute() {
        return null;
    }
}
```